# How to solve this CSS SVG drawn arrow issue. Using position absolute while keeping it responsive

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm working on a project, and normally i'm pretty decent with CSS, but this one just doesn't seem to click for me. Maybe someone here has an idea for fix this thing.

There's this hero design, this hero contains a SVG which I will animate using GSAP later on. The SVG is placed absolutely at this moment in the hero section. it's a drawn line from right to left (not completely to the left), circling the heading (which is on the left part of the container) and at the end pointing to a button. While using position absolute I can position it for a specific viewport, but ofcourse when this shift, the line isn't positioned correctly anymore (specially with using clamped spacing and fontsizes).

I've created a codepen where you can see the idea.

```
.svg {
  position: absolute;
  right: -150px;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/NovamIT/pen/jOQLJeV